# 301 permanent wild redirect

Tags: redirect, litespeed

Need help to redirect any url like:

http://www.example.com/*.html

to:

http://www.example.com/forums/*.html

I am using Litespeed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use that on my lite speed server:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*\.html)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/forums/$1? [R=301,L]
```

as well to check if it works, you can use this website, it helped me a lot when I was figure that out:

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

In general it seem that you can use the same command in litespeed than in apache

Cheers,

William